# Two Way Binding usando Modelos

Tags: html5, angular

Estoy tratando de usar two way binding, pero tengo un error **'Cannot read property 'CardOwnerName' of undefined'**, trate de solucionarlo usando el operador '?' con el fin de evaluar si la propiedad esta en null o vacia, pero sigo con el mismo error. Les comparto el las clases y el HTML.

Gracias de antemano!

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { PaymentDetailService } from '../shared/payment-detail.service';
import { PaymentDetail } from '../shared/payment-detail.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-payment-details',
  templateUrl: './payment-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./payment-details.component.scss']
})
export class PaymentDetailsComponent implements OnInit {


  formDatosTarjeta: FormGroup;
  dataPayment: PaymentDetail;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    public paymentService: PaymentDetailService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
 
  }
  }
```

```html
 <div class="form-group">
            <label>Card owner name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CardOwnerName" formControlName="CardOwnerName" [(ngModel)]="paymentService.formData.CardOwnerName">
            <small *ngIf="formDatosTarjeta.hasError('required', 'CardOwnerName')"
                class="form-text text-muted">Required</small>
        </div>
```

```js
export class PaymentDetail {
    PMid: number;
    CardOwnerName: string;
    CardNumber: string;
    ExpirationDate: string;
    CVV: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En esta parte asociaste `payment-details.component.html` con `PaymentDetailsComponent`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-payment-details',
  templateUrl: './payment-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./payment-details.component.scss']
})
export class PaymentDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
```

Sin embargo quieres usar `CardOwnerName` en `payment-details.component.html` como haces aqui:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="CardOwnerName" formControlName="CardOwnerName" [(ngModel)]="paymentService.formData.CardOwnerName">
            <small *ngIf="formDatosTarjeta.hasError('required', 'CardOwnerName')"
```

Pero `CardOwnerName` no existe en `PaymentDetailsComponent`, entonces nunca va a lograr acceder ahi ya que eso esta en otra clase (`PaymentDetail`).

Para que funcione debes declarar `CardOwnerName` en `PaymentDetailsComponent` ya que esta parte del template:`[(ngModel)]` intenta usar comunicación bidirecional entre el template `payment-details.component.html` y la clase controlador `PaymentDetailsComponent`.

Creo que debe ser algo así:
`<input type="text" class="form-control" name="CardOwnerName" formControlName="CardOwnerName" [(ngModel)]="cardOwnerName">` y en `PaymentDetailsComponent` poner `cardOwnerName: string;`